# How to limit probable entry from user in migration?

Tags: laravel

What if I try to limit possible entries in migration level in Laravel. For instance i have a migration:

```
public function up()
{
   Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->id();
       $table->string('type')
       $table->timestamps();
   });
}
```

Now I want to accept anything from `image, post, bio` for the type column. if the user try to save anything except the 3 options, i want the DB to deny. How can I do so ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `enum` column allowing only the defined values.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-enum

```
$table->enum('type', ['image', 'post', 'bio']);
```